# getting different php session ID evey request I make. angular front end

Tags: php, angular, session, session-cookies

So I have my PHP on a server, and my angular app locally. 
for every request I make, I am getting back a different PHP session id in my network tab. Because of this I cannot test my session cookie as it doesn't exist. 
When I bundle the app and put it on the server (same server as php files) then the sessionID is the same, So I am only having this issue locally. 
I have added the correct CORS on my php file (just above `session_start()`) and I am sending `withCredentials: true` with my request, yet the session is always different.

Is there anything I need to look out for?
I am somewhat a PHP novice and more experienced in Angular so any help is appreciated.

Angular post request:

```
loginSession(form: string) {
const options = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=utf-8'),
  withCredentials: true
}
return this.httpClient.post<any>(`${this.SERVER}/function.php`, form, options);
```

}

```
Response Headers:

access-control-allow-credentials: true
access-control-allow-headers: Content-Type
access-control-allow-methods: POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE, PUT
access-control-allow-origin: http://localhost:4200
cache-control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate
content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
date: Wed, 15 Jan 2020 08:44:27 GMT
expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
pragma: no-cache
server: Apache
status: 200
vary: Accept-Encoding,User-Agent
x-content-encoding-over-network: gzip

Request Headers:

:authority: mysite.com
:method: POST
:path: /function.php
:scheme: https
accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br
accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.9
cache-control: no-cache
content-length: 68
content-type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
cookie: PHPSESSID=93cfc63e3b04eb7bf6f633ae1b11fba7
origin: http://localhost:4200
pragma: no-cache
referer: http://localhost:4200/
sec-fetch-mode: cors
sec-fetch-site: cross-site
user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.117 Safari/537.36
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Possibly your request is not sending cookies with the request. Php requires client side cookies to maintain the session.

Share your code to provide a better answer. But for time being you should made the request with, withCredentials option set to true.

```
let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers, withCredentials: true });

this.http.post(url, data, options)
```

Comment: Hi, I have edited my question to include 1 post request I am making, which includes the headers & withCredentials. Your code using `RequestOptions` is an older version of Angular, I am using Angular 8. A side question I have: Would I need to add options to all of my post requests? Or just the one that I am expecting a cookie?

Comment: You need to add it to all the requests that utilizes session on the server end.

Can you share a request/ response headers for OPTIONS request from chrome/firefox dev tools?
OPTION request must return "Access-Control-Allow-Headers" header with "Content-Type" value or wildcard (*)

Comment: Yes I see in the request for OPTIONS `access-control-allow-headers: Content-Type`

Comment: @DevStacker can you share a request/response details? Another thing you can check is is secure flag on for cookies? If so you must use https unless angular will not be handling cookies

Comment: I have added the response & request headers to my original post. 

Thanks

Comment: Per the headers, server is not sending "Set-Cookie:", which means either session is not initiated on the php side, or php has properly resumed the session based on PHPSESSID cookie. If you share php script can see what's happening on that end.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205992/discussion-between-dryize-and-devstacker).